# Python installed in multiple paths, is this bad?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I am newish to python and Mac and may have messed up when installing python. Will this cause future errors?

Also why are some paths listed multiple times?

```
~ % where python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Hi Mike, well, it's not exactly bad, but it's a situation which is likely to lead to confusion eventually ... It's pretty typical with Python, especially so on macOS. There are multiple ways to install Python and they all have their pluses and minuses. My advice is to try to pick on and focus on it, and delete the others. I use Homebrew and it seems to work well -- maybe keep that one? You might also try asking for a recommendation on apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "delete the others"...yes and NO!  You can delete any of the Python interpreters that you know you installed yourself for development purposes, but NEVER delete a Python version that could possibly have come from an Apple install of any kind.  Any interpreter installed as part of the OS or by Xcode has a high likelihood of being necessary to one or more system tools.  If you remove one of those versions, you may break things that are not part of using that version for software development.  There is no harm in keeping those versions around. When in doubt, leave it alone!

Comment: ...and to answer your question directly...no, it's not bad at all.  I always have at least 3 versions installed: 1) the one Apple installed that Apple tools use, 2) a version other than the newest version that I use unless I have a need for a feature new to the latest version, and 3) the latest version for experimentation and for when I want to use a feature that has been added in that version.

Comment: A related issue is the use of Virtual Environments.  These days, many of us believe that one should use Virtual Envs exclusively, only installing packages into them, never into the base Python installs.  This has at least three benefits 1) you can have specific environments for each of your projects, avoiding package version conflicts and letting you be sure which packages your project needs, 2) lets you install packages without having to be root (without having to sudo), and 3) if a VirtualEnv gets screwed up, you can throw it away and easily build a replacement.

Comment: Try running `which` rather than `where`.  Thats the one that counts.  Recommendation:  install via homebrew or macports.  Then use virtualenv to assign a specific python to each project.

Answer (score 3):

First, what are these?

1. /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 — this was installed by Homebrew.
2. /Library/Frameworks/*whatever* — This was *probably*
   installed by an installation package from the Python website.
3. /usr/bin/python3 — this one probably came with Xcode.

If you want Xcode installed, you're probably not going to get rid of (3), so you just have to get used to it being there. (1) and (2) are a bit redundant together, and if you use Homebrew for other things, there's a decent probability that it will pull in Python anyway as a dependency for something else, so you might as well keep (1) and get rid of (2).

As for why they are listed multiple times, my guess would be that your PATH environment variable contains some directories multiple times. Checking this is easy — just do `echo $PATH` — but fixing it will, I’m afraid, require some debugging of your shell startup files to figure out where the duplicates come from.

(Personally, I keep both the Homebrew-installed one, which I never use or install packages for directly, and the /Library/Frameworks one which is the one I use. The advantage of this is that when Homebrew suddenly decides to change a lot of things around, my stuff stays put. However, having an extra Python around certainly increases the risk for confusion, so I don’t particularly recommend this unless you know what you are doing.)

(So why not just use the Xcode installed one? Well, for starters, I don't like mucking about in /usr/bin if I can avoid it... it looks like `pip` for that would install stuff inside /Applications/Xcode which... just no.)

Comment: +1 on sticking to a single method for installing Python versions.  I use Homebrew exclusively.  I use PyEnv to manage my Python installs.  It has the ability to not only manage what you have already installed, but can itself install new versions.  I don't use its install feature because I already had Homebrew installs when I started using it, and didn't want to mix install methods or uninstall the versions I already had.  It's easy to register Homebrew-installed versions with PyEnv so that it can manage them.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `which` rather than `where`.

Thats the one that counts.

Recommendation:  install via homebrew (which you seem to be using already) or macports.  Then use virtualenv to assign a specific python executable to each project.